# Prevent Apex Map for generic attributes to show up in serialized JSON

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, json

My Apex method is providing data rows with column names and values back to my Lightning component. The component expects this JSON

**I WANT THAT**

```
{    "columns":[
        {
            "sortable":true,
            "label":"Account Name",
            "dataType":"STRING",
            "name":"Name"
        },
    ],
    "rows":[
        {
            "Name":"Edge Communications",
            "Phone":"(512) 757-6000",
            "Website":"http://edgecomm.com"
        },
    ]
}
```

Please note that while the properties of a columns are defined/fixed (the keys will never change) the **rows are totally generic in its properties and values**.

*I now struggle on how to generate this in Apex. The JSON always contains the fields map. As I keep the rows in a **`Map<String, Object>`** this map is also serialized. *

**THIS IS WHAT I GET**

```
{
   "columns":[
      {
         "sortable":true,
         "name":"Attribute",
         "label":"Attribute",
         "dataType":"STRING"
      }
   ],
   "rows":[
      {
         "fields":{
            "name":"Ben",
            "age":33,
            "city":"Detroit"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my data model in Apex

```
public class TableData {

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Col> columns = new List<Col>();
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();


    public class Col {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String label;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String dataType = 'STRING';
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean sortable = true;
    }


    public class Row {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Map<String, Object> fields = new Map<String, Object>();
    }
}
```

and this is how its converted

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String queryData() {
    TableData data = new TableData();

    ...

    return JSON.serialize(data);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an artifact of how you've constructed your data. If you want to avoid "fields", you need to change your data model:

```
public class TableData {
    public List<Col> columns = new List<Col>();
    public List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new List<Map<String, Object>>();

    public class Col {
        public String label;
        public String name;
        public String dataType = 'STRING';
        public Boolean sortable = true;
    }
}
```

Note that @AuraEnabled complains when you use List types, but since you're serializing everything yourself, there's really not much point in using @AuraEnabled all over the place. You'll need to JSON.parse in your controller to reconstitute your data back into real objects.